# Вопрос по mod_rewrite

Tags: mod_rewrite, get

Есть строка запроса:

```
http://site.com/option1/option2/option_50?search=поисковая_строка
```

Как сделать так, чтобы часть строки запроса "`option1/option2/option_50`" попала в `$_GET['options']`, а "`?search=поисковая_строка`" попала в `$_GET['search_string']`?

Также если строка запроса, например, `http://site.com/option1/option2/`, то "`option1/option2/`" попадала в `$_GET['options']`, а переменна `$_GET['search_string']` либо не существовала, либо была пустая.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule (.+) /?options=$1 [QSA] # если требуется редирект, то [QSA,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=(\w+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .+ ?search_string=%1 [L] # если требуется редирект, то [R=301,L]
```

Проверял [здесь](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/). Кажется, в этой песочнице флаг `QSA` не работает.

Про составления правил для mod_rewrite можно почитать [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/company/sprinthost/blog/129560/).

**На будущее:** для таких вещей необходимо [использовать роутинг на бэкенде](https://laravel.ru/docs/v4/routing), а не реврайты.